# script not working after WordPress migration

Tags: jquery, wordpress

On my site I have a draggable div that works by the following code, inserted just before the /head:

```
    <script>   $(function() {
       $( ".gallery" ).draggable(); </script>
```

This is the div in question:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

         <div class="gallery">

             <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
             <?php the_content(); ?>

         </div>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To import the site into Wordpress, I've changed the script and added it to a .js file loaded through functions.php:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".gallery" ).draggable();
});
```

Alerts do work so the .js file is properly loaded but the draggable script doesn't work anymore..

Any help will be much appreciated!

Just to be sure: the functions.php code =

```
<?php    function emilpabon_theme_js() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery/jquery.js', array('jquery', 'lightbox_js', 'smoothscroll_js'), '', true ); 

    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'emilpabon_theme_js' );

    ?>
```

The alert I used (which worked!)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Check the console for any error.

Comment: Is that your actual JS? If so, it's malformed. Make sure you're using proper syntax, and that you're including the library that defines the `draggable()` function.

Comment: can you show the full code, including how you are loading the script

Comment: Should `$( ".gallery" ).draggable();` be `jquery( ".gallery" ).draggable();`? And is jQuery UI loaded?

Comment: @j0869 I know jQuery UI is loaded since alerts work. Tried changing $ for jQuery but no response

Comment: As Kamal asked, are you getting errors in the console? And I don't know what alerts you're referring to since you didn't post any.

Comment: @j08691 The console is stating: jQuery and $ where used before defined.

Comment: @j08691 and missing 'use strict' statement

Comment: @j08691I've added the alert that I used, it worked. So changing $(document).ready(function(){
to jQuery(document).ready(function(){
should make it readable for WordPress right?